# How to integrate Simply Hired XML API with C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xml, xslt

H**Simply hired** provides APIs for accessing job info programmatically.

please have a look at the following URL.

[Simply Hired API call](http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-Embedded+System?pshid=19984&ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=embedded.jobamatic.com&clip=69.181.5.128)

When i make a request with this URL.

I **get some thing like XML. But this doesnt begin with a XML tag . The SImply Hired API provider have also given the DTD to validate against.**

E.g  Response from server *Embedded System Jobs 2010-10-02T02:04:01Z 0 10 20568 1000 Staff Embedded Software Engineer Job Becton Dickinson Becton Dickinson sponsored San Jose, CA 2010-09-30T12:19:22Z 2010-09-11T12:20:17Z Employer About us Description As a senior member of the embedded system team, the Staff Embedded Software Engineer ... Marketing, Research, Research, Technology, Testing, Embedded, Open Source, Informatics,*

If you view the source of the link (Simply Hired link placed above) , you will be able to understand , the response format from the server.

What should i do further to display the received (XML like) response in the web page?

I think something to do with XML , XSLT , CSS intergration etc.

Could someone please assist me?

**Pages using the Simply Hired API are given below.**

http://jobsearch.money.cnn.com

http://jobs.usnews.com

http://www.plaxo.com/myCareer/search/

http://jobs.businessweek.com

http://itjobs.computerworld.com

Comment: Provide minimal input sample and desired output, please.

Comment: If you can't modify this response adding a PI `xml-styleshet`, then you should use Emacscript XSLT. You need to provide desired XHTML output in order to help you.

Comment: @Alejandro : Thanks for the response. Updating my question upon your request.

Comment: We already see the input. You are missing the desired XHTML output.

Comment: @Alenjandro: The Output should be like any one of the sites specified above like jobsearch etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
//load the url in to query url
TextReader = new XmlTextReader(QueryUrl);
TextReader.ReadInnerXml();

// Create a new XmlDocument  
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Load data  
doc.Load(QueryUrl);

// Get forecast with XPath  
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpathtitle);
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode titlenode in nodes)
    {
        if (titlenode != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in titlenode.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child != null)
                {
                    // your code here..
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```